# Define macro from a file using cmake and use it later on the code

Tags: c++, file, cmake, macros

How can I define a macro and its value from a file, using cmake, and then use it later on the code in the proper way?. Here what i have done:

CmakeList.txt

```
file(STRINGS server.txt _SERVERS)
add_definitions(-DSERVERS=${_SERVERS})
```

File server.txt

```
http://192.168.1.150:8080
```

After running cmake i find in the command line the macro:

```
/D "SERVERS=http://192.168.1.150:8080"
```

But when i put in the code main.cpp

```
  QString test = QString(SERVERS);
```

Visual studio marke it as error and it give me the following error, once I pass mouse over the variable:

Error: Identifier "http://192.168.1.150:8080" is undefined

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: for this kind of thing it's often easier and more maintainable to use configure_file() to configure a "config.hpp" header file.

Answer (score 0):

Error is in the file
 The value must be using quotes like

```
"http://192.168.1.150:8080"
```

sorry for the question